# ios: making UIBarButtonItem interact with TabBar navigation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a project that uses a UITabBarController for navigation.  When users navigate to other views from the main one on the tab bar, I would like to include a toolbar at the top of those other views with a back button that, when clicked, would essentially select the home button of the tab bar.  This is obviously a redundant feature but I wanted to include it for ease of use.  How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, just make an IBAction and link it to the bar button. Then add the following to the action.

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```